# Can I generate the full public key from a fingerprint?

Tags: ssh, cryptography, travis-ci

Working with travis-ci, and they provide a default public key it seems but only the fingerprint is available (`1b:fe:b0:e4:dd:94:ba:46:6a:91:23:60:4a:a7:d0:46`).

I know this is generally a processed version (md5 digest with base64 usually) of the public key - is it possible to reverse?

I understand hashes in cryptography are only valuable because they generally cannot be reversed, but since md5 has been broken...

Comment: No, it cannot be reversed, no matter how broken MD5 may be.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk respectfully I think it practically could be "reversed" in that you could conceivably come up with `n` messages that would result in that specific md5 digest and then add them (either one by one or all) to the `authorized_key` file

Comment: That is not what you asked -- or at least not the way I interpreted it. I thought you were asking if you could reverse it to recover a *specific* public key.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk a specific key would be necessary, but it would also presumably be in the subset of all recovered/possible keys...

Comment: Yes, but two points: 1) There are practically an infinite number of keys that have any given MD5 hash. Although you can restrict these by e.g. only looking for 2048 bit keys RSA keys there would still be too many to work with, and 2) as far as I know the existing MD5 attacks are not able and do not attempt to recover *every* possible preimage.

Answer (score 3):

Considering what [fingerprinting is](https://superuser.com/a/422008/141), no.

As [mentioned here](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-0-387-73003-5_60)

> Fingerprint hashing is merging fingerprint recognition and cryptographic methods. The aim is to perform a recognition using fingerprint while, at the same time, hiding the private information related to the fingerprint, thus enabling public fingerprint templates.

It is a [one-way hash function](https://medium.com/@Triaslab/one-way-hash-function-a-fingerprint-to-get-message-7a14e9268596), even with md5:

> A one-way hash function, also known as a message digest, fingerprint or compression function, is a mathematical function which takes a variable-length input string and converts it into a fixed-length binary sequence.

Comment: Since MD5 is "broken" and base64 is obfuscation/encoding not encryption, is it not theoretically possible to come up with some messages that would produce the correct digest (and therefore fingerprint)?

Comment: @BrianBrownton Possible (https://hashtoolkit.com/reverse-md5-hash/), but generally for password through a database. I don't know it was done for public SSH keys (which are considerably longer than your usual password)

Comment: @BrianBrownton fingerprints alone can be problematic: https://www.delaat.net/rp/2010-2011/p20/report.pdf